# Low resolution of texture when I paint on my model

Tags: modeling, materials, image

I have very bad resolution if i paint or change all texture of model.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more of a description of what is wrong and the steps you have taken? What do you mean by bad resolution? Is your texture image high enough resolution to start with? Are you having problems because of trying to zoom in and out and paint while the brush rescales based on zoom? Have you tried painting in the UV/2D Image Editor instead?

Comment: I would like to texture that in my 3D view using texture paint. I would like paiting that texture but its very bad resolution, you can see it on the background of image. In front of image is the texture, you can see that this texture is very good resolution.

Comment: What size is your target image in pixel resolution versus the image you are using to stencil paint? The mesh looks faceted so it is hard to tell what resolution you are using.